# How to Share an API Between React Components

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I have an API that returns all the objects loved by a user in a system (`GET /loves.json`). I'm showing a set of objects and would like to use a single call to the API to 'color' if a user has loved a given product using react. Thus far I have:

**components/love.js.jsx.coffee**:

```
class Components.Love extends React.Component
  @propTypes =
    id: React.PropTypes.number
    type: React.PropTypes.string

  constructor: (props) ->
    super(props)
    @state = Loves.Fetcher.shared()

  loved: ->
    this.state.loved(@props.id, @props.type)

  text: ->
    if @loved() then "Loved" else "Unloved"

  render: ->
    return React.DOM.div {}, @text()
```

**loves/fetcher.js.coffee**:

```
class Loves.Fetcher
  instance = null
  @shared: -> instance ?= new Loves.Fetcher

  constructor: ->
    @fetch()

  loved: (id, type) ->
    return ...

  fetch: ->
    $.get "/loved.json", (data) -> ...
```

**index.html**:

```
<h1>Shoes</h1>
<div data-react-class="Components.Love" data-react-props="{'id':1,'type':'Product'}"></div>

<h1>Pants</h1>
<div data-react-class="Components.Love" data-react-props="{'id':2,'type':'Product'}"></div>

<h1>Again</h1>
<div data-react-class="Components.Love" data-react-props="{'id':1,'type':'Product'}"></div>

<h1>Pants (Again)</h1>
<div data-react-class="Components.Love" data-react-props="{'id':2,'type':'Product'}"></div>
```

However, I'm unsure of how to proceed. What is the React way of informing components when state has changed (via an HTTP request for example) to get them to update? Any other good ways for sharing API results (I definitely don't want an HTTP request per love component)? I'd like to be able to place the love component anywhere and not rely on a parent / child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start using [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/). In the Flux architecture, your components would trigger actions, e.g., the `getLove` action. This action would be intercepted and dispatched to a store, say the `LoveStore`.

The `Store` holds the data that represents the model of your application (or part of it). An `Action` modifies the model. In your case, the `LoveStore`, because of a `getLove` action, would trigger the `GET` request, fetch the data and update the model.

Once the model is updated, the `LoveStore` publishes the changes. The components that need that data would be listening for changes in `LoveStore`: Once they have been notified, they update their internal state. Updating their internal state would trigger the `render()` method.

You can see a few benefits:

- The model is decoupled from your components
- The API can be centralized in a different file (`LoveFetcher`), and called by the store, the only entity that can access and modify the model
- Using the publish/subscribe pattern, components interested in data changes listen to the proper store and that's it
- The data flow is **unidirectional**, the big feature of the Flux architecture, which guarantees the consistency of every component with the page model.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container component that holds the data as state, and pass it to the child components as properties.

[More info in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html)

The child components would be the `Components.Love` class you wrote, but you have to change these components so they don't have `loved` as state, but as a property that is brought in by the parent component.

Comment: What if this isn't really an easy option? For example - in the above the love component is recycled across a number of different pages and different places - and this is an initial integration of react - so not everything is written in react.

Comment: Then start using Flux straight away.